# mongoose foreign key some field are disabled (not show when call api)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

**I have two schema:** 
(1) authSchema 
(2) bookSchema

```js
const authSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  }
});

const bookSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  authors: [{
      authId: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "auth",
        required: true
      }
  }],

  title: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  }
});
```

And my get route

```js
// Auth = new mongoose.model("auth", authSchema);

app.get("/", (req, res, next) => {
  Auth.find({})
    .select({
      __v: 0,
      _id: 0,
    })
})
```

Then the output is:
[pastebin link](https://pastebin.com/Qjz2C5Nv)

*** **But I want to data the below format**
[pastebin link](https://pastebin.com/99fM3AV6)

What changes make this output!
thanks!

Comment: add `"authors._id": 0` to `select`

Comment: it's not worked!